# Display my location in embedded google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using iframe to display embedded google maps:

```html
<iframe
    id="map_canvas" name="map_canvas"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=205427380680792264646.0004fe643d107ef29299a&amp;output=embed"
    width="100%" height="600px">
</iframe>
```

And I would like to add a placemarker to this iframe, which will display my current location, without the need to redirect to google maps webpage.

I tried to implement it with this script, but it doesnt work:

Could you help me please ?

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
var watchId;
var map;
var myLocation;
var myLocationMarker = null;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(58, 16),
        zoom : 7,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = map = new google.maps.Map(document
            .getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var optn = {
            enableHighAccuracy : true,
            timeout : Infinity,
            maximumAge : 0
        };
        watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition,
                showError, optn);
    } else {
        alert('Geolocation is not supported in your browser');
    }

}

function showPosition(position) {

    if (myLocationMarker != null) {
        myLocationMarker.setMap(null);
    }

    myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude);

    myLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : myLocation,
        map : map
    });

}

function showError(error) {
    switch (error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
        break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        alert("Location information is unavailable.");
        break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
        alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
        break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        alert("An unknown error occurred.");
        break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please define *It doesn't work*

Comment: Browser asks me if I want to share my location, I accept it, but on the map doens't appear the marker at my location.

Comment: You are declaring the `var map` globally, then you declare it again in the `initialize` function. There you should read `map = new google.maps.Map ...` Also if you want the map to show your location, you should add a `map.setCenter(myLocation);` in `showPosition()` function.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: What problem? Your script works fine! Or I didn't get what the problem was. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/r323b/

Comment: It works only if I place a map to a div as you have done, but I need to place a map to an iframe like here: http://jsfiddle.net/FsuF8/ 
I cannot see my location in iframe, that's the problem.

Comment: I see. I didn't get that. I don't think you can mix the API and the embeded maps, or I don't know why. You could think about converting the embed map to the API.